# Calling activity method in custom adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

So I am currently trying to refresh a `recyclerview` in another `activity` but the problem is it doesn't like the `casting` or the way I am calling it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the crashlog, it would appear you are passing an ApplicationContext to your recyclerview. Instead, you need to pass your activity as Context, and ensure your Activity implements the UserRView interface.

A cleaner way would be to pass a context and also pass a UserRView to your adapter, so you do not have to cast the context to UserRView, and you can continue to pass an application context if you prefer.

Edit: replace this code

```
adapter = new CustomRAdapter(list, getBaseContext());
```

with

```
adapter = new CustomRAdapter(list, this);
```

Comment: Hi, `UserRView` extends `Activity` but the `recyclerview` is in that class. I am trying to do exactly what you suggest which is to pass a context but how do I do that. Could you please modify my code if you dont mind

Comment: Please post your UserRView code (at least the part where you instantiate the RecyclerView) and I'll happily have a look.

Comment: thank you I have updated my post and uploaded my `UserRView` class. It is the `displayAll()` that I am trying to call in order to refresh the `recyclerview`

Comment: Hi, so the code doesn't crash but the actual cardview in the recycler does not get deleted? Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure about that, you'll have to step through the delete code in the debugger, it's not pasted here. Are you refreshing your adapter (notifyDataSetchnaged() or any of its variants?)

Comment: well i mean the `displayAll()` should fetch new values from the DB and update accordingly - but it doesnt

Comment: Sure, its in the `UserStorage` class. It does work, but the cardview in the recyclerview doesnt update on the fly - i.e. as soon as it is deleted

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything wrong by just looking at the code. I'm afraid you'll need to set a breakpoint to confirm the entry is deleted, you are notifying the adapter as expected, so my only guess is that the entry is not deleted. You can try to dump the database contents before and after the delete operation.

Comment: IT WORKS NOW. I forgot to clear the list. Thanks for your help. I will accept the answer